# Dúvida sobre inicialização de membro de dados const

Tags: c++

> "A 'constância' de um objeto const é imposta a partir do momento em que o construtor completa
>   a inicialização do objeto até o destrutor desse objeto ser chamado" - Deitel,Como Programar C++

Se o compilador so "considera" um membro const apos a inicialização do objeto pelo construtor, por que uma inicialização por atribuição gera erros ? Por que só é aceita uma inicialização por inicializador de membro ?

Exemplos:

```
class Example
{ 
   public:
    const int num1;
    int num2;   

   Example(int a, int b)  
   {
      num1 = a; // Gera um erro
      num2 = b;
   }    
}
```

---

```
class Example
{ 
   public:
    const int num1;
    int num2;   

   Example(int a, int b)
    : num1(a) // Funciona normalmente
   {
      num2 = b; 
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Por que só é aceita uma inicialização por inicializador de membro ?

Simples. A inicialização dos membros é completa antes do corpo do construtor começar a executar.

Isto daqui:

```
num1 = a;
```

É atribuição, e não inicialização. Atribuição em variáveis constantes é proibido na linguagem. Agora, isto daqui:

```
Example(int a, int b) : num1(a) { ...
```

É inicialização. Seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
const int num1(42);
```

Ou:

```
const int num1 = 42;
```

Porque quando usa-se o `=` na declaração da variável, aí sim considera-se como inicialização, e não atribuição.