# Qual o motivo da existência de inicializadores de membros

Tags: c++

Em C++ temos os inicializadores de membros const.

1) Por qual motivo esse recurso existe ?

2) Como ele age por debaixo dos panos ?

Comment: Não é a mesma? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/355923/101

Comment: Na verdade nessa outra pergunta nao é questionado o porque desse recurso existir.

Comment: É tudo o que pergunta lá. E eu só não respondi porque dei tudo menos porque ele existe.

Comment: Defina melhor o que você quis dizer com "por debaixo dos planos." Você quer saber como a especificação define o comportamento de initializer list? Ou qual é o código gerado por compiladores? Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Por qual motivo esse recurso existe?

Para ser possível escolher a *inicialização* dos membros além da inicialização padrão.

Usemos um exemplo prático para a explicação:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

struct Data {
    string s;
    int i;

    Data(const string &s, int i) {
        this->s = s;
        this->i = i;
    }
};
```

No código acima (que obviamente não está escrito da maneira mais eficiente de propósito), quando a estrutura `Data` for instanciada com o construtor definido por nós (i.e., aquele que recebe uma `std::string` e um `int`), os seguintes passos irão ocorrer em ordem:

1. Inicializar todos os membros em ordem (nesse caso, uma `std::string` e um `int`) com inicialização padrão (isto é, o membro de dado `s` terá seu construtor padrão chamado e a string inicializará como vazia, e o `i` ficará sem valor definido).
2. Chamar o construtor `Data(const string &s, int i)`.
3. Atribuir o valor do parâmetro `s` para o membro de dado `s` e atribuir o valor do parâmetro `i` para o membro de dado `i`.

O problema dessa abordagem é que `s` é inicializado uma vez e depois atribuído com um outro valor. Seria mais eficiente se o membro de dado `s` fosse inicializado uma vez diretamente com o valor do parâmetro `s` do construtor, sem precisar de atribuição posterior, correto? É para exatamente isso que serve a lista de inicialização de membros:

```
struct Data {
    string s;
    int i;

    Data(const string &s, int i) s(s), i(i) {}
};
```

Utilizando a lista de inicialização como no código acima, teremos os seguintes passos em ordem:

1. Inicializar todos os membros em ordem. Por conta do construtor apresentar uma lista de inicialização de membro `s(s), i(i)`, iremos usar os valores passados para eles (os parâmetros `s` e `i`) para inicializar os membros `s` e `i`, em vez de fazer inicialização padrão. Isto é, o membro `s` chama o construtor de cópia, e o `i` faz inicialização direta.
2. Chamar o construtor `Data(const string &s, int i)`. Nesse caso, como o construtor está vazio, nada acontece.

Perceba que menos passos ocorreram no segundo código comparado com o primeiro código.

Outro detalhe também importante: membros constantes e referências só são inicializáveis através da lista de inicialização de membro.

> Como ele age por debaixo dos planos?

A definição de inicialização de membros por lista é um tanto extensa, então deixo aqui a referência para a especificação: [[class.base.init]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.base.init). Para outras explicações, refira-se ao [cppreference em initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).